# Kali Linux Boot Image Authentication

Tags: bios, kali-linux, secure-boot

I recently discovered Kali Linux and decided to make a live USB so that I could boot it on any available (64-bit) machine. In the process, I also discovered the common "Selected boot image did not authenticate" error and the solution of disabling Secure Boot in the machine's BIOS settings.

But, as a modern OS, shouldn't Kali be authenticate-able (i.e. so that Secure Boot will work)? Is this even feasible for the developers? I would assume so, since I know from experience that Ubuntu (among other distros) works with Secure Boot, but I'm relatively unfamiliar with Linux internals, so I don't know how difficult it might be to make that work.

If this is possible, shouldn't Kali Linux, as a security-centered distro, be taking full advantage of a security feature like that? (I mean, they recommend that you verify the ISO's SHA256 checksum after downloading, after all, so using Secure Boot seems like a pretty obvious thing to do.)